# Existence of two "pairwise-inverse" sign functions on [n]

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n\in{}\mathbb{N}$. Does there exists two functions $f,g:[n]\to{}\{-1,1\}$ s.t $\forall{}i\neq{}j\in{}[n]$, it holds that $f(i)f(j)=-g(i)g(j)$?

(in a sense, $f$ and $g$ are inverting all products of pairs of indices)

If so, can we construct these functions explicitly for all $n$, rather than prove existence?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Only for small $n$. If $n\ge 3$, then
$$\begin{align} 1&=g(1)^2g(2)^2g(3)^2\\&=g(1)g(2)\cdot g(2)g(3)\cdot g(3)g(1)
\\&=(- f(1)f(2))\cdot(- f(2)f(3))\cdot (-f(3)f(1))\\&=-f(1)^2f(2)^2f(3)^2\\&=-1\end{align}$$